# Fourier’s separation of variable for BVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I got this problem: Use Fourier’s separation of variables method to solve the following BVP ( in polar coordinates, i.e. , `u=u(ρ,α)` ):

\begin{cases}
Δu    = 0         , for ρ<2\\
\\
u|_{ρ=2}=(sin α)^2
\end{cases}
,but I got lost halfway...
So far I got: "suppose u is separable, u=R(ρ)Φ(α) where both R and Φ are functions. -> the equation becomes R''Φ+RΦ''= 0 => R''/R = -Φ''/Φ but since those two fractions are independent of the other variables, then the fractions are constant. So i equal them to lambda: R'' - λR=0 and Φ''+λΦ=0" but this is just information I put together from the internet/forums. I don't really know how to use those values, sadly..

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: You are missing the key point of separation of variables. If you take two functions $f$ and $g$, the only way that the equation $f(x)=g(y)$ can be true for all possible inputs $(x,y)$ is if both of the functions $f,g$ are constant functions.